# BeautifulSoup with Selenium for ASPX

Tags: python, asp.net, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this page (*AAG* is only as example):

https://bvb.ro/FinancialInstruments/Details/FinancialInstrumentsDetails.aspx?s=AAG

The main 'issue' is most of the page's content changes when cycling through the 'buttons' (`<input type='submit'`) under the *ctl00_body_IFTC_btnlist* `<div>` (visible as *Overview* / *Trading* / *Charts* / *News* / *Financials* / *Issuer profile* for the English version).

Using Selenium with a Chrome (version 98) driver, I am able to navigate through the subsections (via XPATH):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = Options()
# options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'D:\\Python\\workspace\\vs-code\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://bvb.ro/FinancialInstruments/Details/FinancialInstrumentsDetails.aspx?s=AAG')
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/input[2]')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', link)
```

(Please note, I use `--start-maximized` not only for easier troubleshooting, but also because `--headless` gets blocked.)

My main issue is when I try to parse the page after having 'clicked the button'.
Namely, if I do `soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')`, I still have the initial page as the URL default opens (on the first subsection, *Overview*).

This is consistent with manual navigation (through those 6 subsections) via a Chrome browser. The URL never changes, and if I do `Right Click -> View page source` I always have the initial version.

Now, if I (manually) do `Right Click -> Inspect` on an element of interest, I do find what I am looking for.

I am not sure how to best get this done programmatically ('navigate' through a page using Selenium, but also be able to parse the 'updated' content with BeautifulSoup).

Edit: Answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the `driver` object holds the exact information I need.

So, what I do is:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('ID_OF_ELEMENT').get_attribute('innerHTML')
```